# Difference between creative commons and GPL?

Tags: gpl, license-compatibility, cc-by-sa

Why shouldn't I release code under a Creative Commons License?

For me the CC-BY-SA sounds very nice and is quite more readable than a whole GPL license, so I would like to know why its such a bad idea to release code with this license.

Comment: When you say that the CC license sounds better, make sure that you're not looking at the license deed (human-readable summary). That summary *is not* the license, and the actual license is probably less readable than that of the GPL.